# I am unable send multiple data to new activity through a single button click

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to send data from `MainActivity` through two text boxes with a single button click to send the data to `SecondActivity` which should display both numbers one below the other.

But the `SecondActivity` is either showing the first or the second textbox's data and not both.

What am I doing wrong here?

Code From MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String MESSAGE_KEY="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key";
    public final static String MESSAGE_KEY2="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void compute(View v) {

        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        String message= e1.getText().toString();
        String message2= e2.getText().toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,message);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY2,message2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

From Second Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String MESSAGE_KEY="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key";
    public final static String MESSAGE_KEY2="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY2);

        TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);

        TextView textView2=new TextView(this);
        textView2.setText(message2);
        setContentView(textView2);

        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the second activity to `LinearLayout`, from `AppCompatActivity` to `Activity`, added the same ID as `MainActivity` textbox's ID to `TextView`, tried different ID's as well, removed `TextView` entirely, but still not getting the output of both numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but I laughed at "AppCombatActivity" ... It's AppCompatActivity...

Comment: `setContentView` what do you think that does?

Comment: *"still not getting the output of both numbers"*...if you're not getting a valid value, you must be getting NPE. Can you post what exactly you are receiving?

Comment: @njzk2 I cannot believe I missed that :p. Maybe post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to code below:

second_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

SecondActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

    TextView tvFirst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tvScnd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY2);

    tvFirst.setText(message);
    tvScnd.setText(message2);
}
```

Comment: @Madhu if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key";
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY2="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    compute(); //view initialization must be on onCreate
}

public void compute(){

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    String message= e1.getText().toString();
    String message2= e2.getText().toString();

    Intent intent=new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,message);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY2,message2);
    startActivity(intent);

   }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key";
public final static String MESSAGE_KEY2="experiment.com.anew.madhu.assignment.message_key2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY2);

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(message);
    textView2.setText(message2)
   }
}
```